# Is there a measure theoretic proof for this statement?

Tags: measure-theory

It can be proven that

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|<\infty\rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|^2<\infty.$$

This can be proven by noting that if we have convergence then $|a_i|$ must be small for large i, so then $|a_i|^2$ must be smaller and hence we have convergence.

But I am wondering if this can be seen from a result in measure theory using the counting measure, and using integration?

Comment: by example Hölders inequality, that is, if $\|a\|_1<\infty$ then $\|a\|_2\le\|a\|_1\|a\|_\infty<\infty$

Answer (score 2):

By Tonelli's theorem $A = (\sum |a_i|)^2=\sum_i \sum_j |a_i||a_j|<\infty$; now note that $\sum_i|a_i|^2 = \sum_i \sum_j \delta_{ij}|a_i||a_j| \le A<\infty$.  (Where $\delta_{ij}=1 \text{ or }0$ if $i= j$ or not.)